# Retrieve values from datatype

Tags: haskell, syntax, algebraic-data-types

I'm trying to implement an object graph in Haskell, and I have a simple `Node` type which contains a identifier and a list of connected nodes.

```
data Node = Node Integer [Node] deriving (Show)
```

My problem is operating on these types - specifically retrieving the values. For example, I want to look at the `Integer` value within the node; maybe find the item with id = 0

```
nodes = [Node 0 []]
[n | n <- nodes, fst n == 0]

• Couldn't match expected type ‘(Integer, b0)’
                  with actual type ‘Node’
    • In the first argument of ‘fst’, namely ‘n’
      In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘fst n’
      In the expression: fst n == 0
```

Okay, so I can't use `fst`. I can't use `!!` either. I *can* write a function that pulls out the value like

```
nodeId :: Node -> Integer
nodeId (Node i _) = i
```

and now `[n | n <- nodes, nodeId n == 0]` will work.

Is there another way to get values from datatypes like this? Is this the right pattern?

Answer (score 8):

The only way to get values out of a data constructor is indeed to pattern-match on it. If you want, you can define a function that does it, as you have done with `nodeId`, or you can just do the pattern matching inline. For example, you could write

```
[n | n@(Node id _) <- nodes, id == 0]
```

Or, since a list comprehension skips values for which a pattern fails, a shorter version would be

```
[n | n@(Node 0 _) <- nodes]
```

Comment: This is great. I see weird behavior when I try to use a variable in place of the `0` in your second example - the variable is assigned to rather than used as evaluation.

Comment: Haskell isn't prolog. If you have some prior variable, say `x = 0` and want to ensure `id == 0` then you can't match with `Node x _` - that just shadows the variable `x` (it is a new variable unrelated to the prior x).  Instead, you can use a guard solution such as `[n | n@(Node id _) <- nodes, id == x]`.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use record syntax to generate accessor functions for the fields:

```
data Node = Node { nodeId :: Integer,
                   children :: [Node]
                 } deriving (Show)

[n | n <- nodes, nodeId n == 0]
```

Although this has the downside that it's polluting; it creates functions based on the field names. That means you can't have two records that have fields with the same name. You also can't have your own functions with the same name as the field name of the record.

As @K. A. Buhr mentions though, [GHC does have an extension](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/records/overloaded-record-fields/duplicate-record-fields) to help alleviate at least one of these problems.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst Np. I'll note though that using records does have downsides. Since it generates functions based on the record field names, you can't have two records with the same names for fields, as that would cause a conflict. It'll also causes conflicts with any existing functions with the same name.

Comment: Though, as usual, there is a GHC extension (`DuplicateRecordFields`) that can help with the first part of this problem.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr That I actually didn't know about, although it doesn't surprise me. I'll add something in in a sec. Thanks.